# WPF Path looks different then the path inside an svg

Tags: wpf, svg, path

The following path in WPF is drawn as

```
 <Path x:Name="SortIcon" Fill="Black" Width="8" Data="M -5.215,6.099L 5.215,6.099L 0,0L -5.215,6.099 Z" />
```

[image]

When I use the Data inside an svg I am getting a different result

```
<svg height="8" width="8">
   <path d="M -5.215,6.099L 5.215,6.099L 0,0L -5.215,6.099 Z" />
</svg>
```

[image]

Shouldn't they be the same? It seems like WPF rotates the shape.

Comment: Looks clipped rather than rotated to me. Perhaps you're drawing it outside the canvas area. The negative value for the M suggests it may (by default) be to the left of your canvas area.

Comment: In the data string you have negative coordinates. The second image is the same as the first only cropped in half. You will need a viewBox attribute for the svg element. Please try `<svg viewBox="-6 -1 12 6">`

Comment: @RobertLongson svg is provided

Comment: @enxaneta that was helpful, I think now I understand what's happening.

Comment: So it's clipped by the canvas bounds as I originally stated. I.e. the left edge of the shape is outside the canvas.

Comment: @RobertLongson thanks a lot. I misunderstood at the beginning, now it's clear.